# Передача данных с ListView в RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-intent

Есть массив объектов у которого есть геттеры "Категория","Продукт","Количество".

Требуется список из категорий, кликнув по которому открывается список с продуктами и их количеством соответствующей категории.

Для этого я отсортировал массив, чтобы получить уникальные категории и вывел их в `ListView`, также я создал `Fragment` с `RecyclerView`, который должен получить значение `String` от `ListView` по какой категории отображать список... собственно из этого и вопрос, как из `ListView` передать значение в `RecyclerView`.

```
public class ListDirectory extends Activity {
private ListView mListViews;
//    public final static String EXTRA_SORT_ITEM = "extra_sort_item"; мои попытки
private List<String> createListDirectories(){ DirectLab mDirectLab = DirectLab.get(this);
    return DirectLab.getCatName(mDirectLab);}//возвращает имена категорий без дублирования

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
    mListViews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, createListDirectories());
    mListViews.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListViews.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListDirectory.this, Direct_activity_list.class);
 //                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SORT_ITEM, createListDirectories().get(position)); мои попытки
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });}}



public class Direct_fragment_list extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mDirectRecyclerView;
private DirectAdapter mAdapter;
private Direct mDirect;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.direct_fragment_list, container, false);
    mDirectRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.direct_recycler_view);
    mDirectRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    updateUI();
    return view;
}
 private void updateUI() {
    DirectLab directLab = DirectLab.get(getActivity());
    mAdapter = new DirectAdapter(DirectLab.getSortItem("ЗНАЧЕНИЕ КОТОРОЕ ТРЕБУЕТСЯ ПОЛУЧИТЬ ОТ LISTVIEW", directLab));
    mDirectRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Ну и сами методы по которым сортировал:

```
 public static List<String> getCatName(DirectLab directLab) { //возвращает уникальные названия категорий
    dir = new HashSet<>();
    for (Direct d : directLab.getDirects()) {
        dir.add(d.getName_directory());
    }
    catName = new ArrayList<>(dir);
    return catName;
}

public static List<Direct> getSortItem(String s, DirectLab directLab) {
    List<Direct> sortDirectory = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Direct d : directLab.getDirects()) {
        if (d.getName_directory().equals(s)) sortDirectory.add(d);
    }
    return sortDirectory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

все оказалось очень просто, требовалось просто в параметры`mAdapter = new DirectAdapter(DirectLab.getSortItem("ЗНАЧЕНИЕ КОТОРОЕ ТРЕБУЕТСЯ ПОЛУЧИТЬ ОТ LISTVIEW", directLab));`передать`getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(ListDirectory.EXTRA_SORT_ITEM);`